# JHipster: Enable anonymous users to read entity, but not update?

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster

I have generated a JHipster application using these values:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.1.0",
    "baseName": "app",
    "packageName": "my.app",
    "packageFolder": "my/app",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "",
    "useSass": true,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
 }
```

I would like to allow anonymous users to view an entity, but not update or delete that entity.  I have tried editing the generated `SecurityConfiguration.java` file to add `permitAll(HttpMethod.GET,"/**")` for `authorizeRequests()` in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.  I still get directed to `accessdenied` when trying to access the entity.

Has anyone addressed this use case before?

Comment: In the method `configure(WebSecurity web)`, I also added  `ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**")` to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for AngularJS 1.x

For accessing the resources: in `SecurityConfiguration.java` in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method

```
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
```

For accessing the angular views/states: for each entity, comment out or remove the `authorities` property for read-only states. Below an example for `Book` entity in `src/main/webapp/app/entities/book/book.state.js`:

```
    .state('book', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/book',
        data: {
            // authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'monoApp.book.home.title'
        },
        ....
    })
    .state('book-detail', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/book/{id}',
        data: {
            // authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'monoApp.book.detail.title'
        },
```

However, pay attention to 2 things:

- By using such a pattern in `SecurityConfiguration`, you also expose your users at `/api/users`. It would be safer to add a `permitAll()` per entity so that you keep full control on what you expose (whitelist approach)
- The user experience is poor as you still expose buttons for adding or deleting entities. So you could hide them with ng-hide

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  I really enjoy jHipster and thanks for your excellent contribution.

Comment: I'm running Jhipster 4.3.0 and Angular 4 and and want a blog post to be public (anonymous user). I have added .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll() .antMatchers("/entry/**").permitAll() to SecurityConfiguration.java and removed, authorities: ['ROLE_USER'] from src/main/webapp/app/entities/entry/entry.route.ts but I can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please ask your own question

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [@Gaël Marziou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93960/ga%C3%ABl-marziou) but I think instead of allow permit all to GET /api, add new prefix like

> /public

and authorization:

```
.antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
```

for all public apis may look better