# JHipster: Enable anonymous users to read entity, but not update it

Tags: security, spring-security, jhipster, angular5

I have generated a JHipster application using these values:

```
{   
    "generator-jhipster": 
    {
        "jhipsterVersion": "4.13.0",
        "baseName": "app",
        "packageName": "my.app",
        "packageFolder": "my/app",
        "serverPort": "8080",
        "authenticationType": "session",
        "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
        "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
        "websocket": "no",
        "databaseType": "sql",
        "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
        "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
        "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
        "buildTool": "gradle",
        "enableSocialSignIn": false,
        "rememberMeKey": "",
        "clientFramework": "angularX",
        "useSass": true,
        "applicationType": "monolith",
        "testFrameworks": [],
        "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
        "enableTranslation": false  
    }  
}
```

I would like to allow anonymous users to view an entity, but not update or delete that entity.

I have tried editing the generated **SecurityConfiguration.java** file to add `permitAll(HttpMethod.GET,"/**")` for `authorizeRequests()` in the configure(HttpSecurity http) method.

```
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/products").permitAll()
```

I am still getting this message when I try  to access the entity.

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

I know is similar to this question: [JHipster: Enable anonymous users to read entity, but not update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899967/jhipster-enable-anonymous-users-to-read-entity-but-not-update)

I have tried to use the same solution here but it's not working.  Is there something I should change in the front end ?

Can you help me on this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `@Secured` annotation on rest controller methods like in `UserResource.java`? Similarly on frontend routes using authorities as documented in http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular?

Comment: I did put the `@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.ANONYMOUS)` on my resource method and the route in the frontend  is set with: 'authorities: []'.  Still

Comment: As you put permitAll() you should NOT have annotated the method anonymously accessed and use `@Secured` with real roles only on other methods of your controller that requires privileges. For the angular routes, I don't know you don't give enough details no debug trace in browser console to know what's wrong.